# Why to declare array before setting it (php)?

Tags: php, arrays

I dont know why people declare array before loops and etc..:

```
$new= array();      // <----- why this is needed ?
foreach($something as $v){
    $new[] = $v;
}
```

Why to declare the array before setting its value?  (In other languages, i.e. C# and JAVA it is needed, but why in PHP?)

Comment: Technically it is not needed, but good practice. Because if the array already exists you just add new values to it, so by assigning an empty array you make sure that the array is empty.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php, and the `Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax` section. `It is always better to initialize a variable by a direct assignment.`

Comment: @Chris85, that's why I've asked... "it's better", but why?    @ Rizier, thanks, it's good argument.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting its value, you're pushing a new element onto the array. But there needs to be an empty array to push onto.